# Code keeps jumping to another function without being referred to

Tags: excel, vba

In below code when I jump to the line

- `Range("Asset_Repline_num").value = Range("repline_start").value - 1 + CA`,

it keeps taking me to another function in another code module. If I comment the other function out it works fine. What am i doing wrong here? Also `Range("repline_start").value = value` keeps becoming "value" and not "Value". Is there anything wrong here?

```
Sub sumsingleassetr()
    TotalPeriod = 100

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    ReDim rngscheduled_bal(1 To TotalPeriod, 0)

    CA_Rep = Range("repline_end").value - Range("repline_start").value + 1
    TotalRepline = CA_Rep

    CA = 0
    For i = 1 To CA_Rep
        CA = CA + 1
        If CA <= CA_Rep Then

           Range("Asset_Repline_num").value = Range("repline_start").value - 1 + CA
        End If

    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a `Worksheet_Change` Event?

Comment: `value keeps becoming "value" and not "Value". Is there anything wrong here?` This usually happens when you declare a variable with that name. Try and find that variable. If it is not there then type `Dim Value as Long` on top of the code and press enter. Then delete that line. Hopefully it should resolve the issue

Comment: Do you call your function somewhere in your sheet(s)? Or is the function Volatile?